# Git not syncing local and remote. How can I sync them using basic git commands?

Tags: git, synchronization

I have a remote repo named experiment_dwn, with one branch named main.
For some reason, git isn't synced between the local and remote counterparts.
`git push` - outputs that everything is up to date, while the remote repository doesn't get updated, and also the following `git status` still shows I have changes to be committed.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

```
user@host:~/Git/experiment_dwn$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
user@host:~/Git/experiment_dwn$ git push
Everything up-to-date
user@host:~/Git/experiment_dwn$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   test.ipynb
```

I tried to search in SO and found some ways to checkout, track and set upstream and none if it worked.

The only thing I haven't tried is removing the git tracking and cloning from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit that change before it can be pushed. Run `git commit` before `git push`.

`git status` does not connect to the remote; it only shows what's changed based on what it already knows from the last `git fetch` or `git pull`.

Answer (score -2):

Solved.

Apparently, my git user name and email were not updated. I am not sure for what reason, since it has been before.

Set username:

```
git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
```

Set email address:

```
git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

Comment: These values have no effect on pushing, fetching, or pulling.